# PowerShell: Change cell color in HTML table based on value or IF statements

Tags: html, css, powershell, colors

Evening guys. I've got a function I've been working on as part of a script I've got that creates a nested hashtable of software information and creates an HTML table. I've got the table working and I like how it is, but I'd like to have a cell (or maybe just the text colors in certain cells) change color based on if certain values match.

My thoughts are either a Status column and having the background color change, or have the text in Installed Version & Expected Version columns change color.I don't know if it's possible with how I'm compiling the table, and it isn't a end of the world thing if it won't work, more of a "be cool if it could" kind of thing.

**My Overall Question is:** How can I change the background color of a cell in the "Status" column based on if two certain values match. Or alternatively have the text color change in a cell for the "Installer Version" and "Expected Versions" columns. Below is my function

Note: I am extremely new to HTML/CSS languages. This is what I've been able to put together with a lot of googling and reading.

```
Function Get-SoftwareVersions{
<#
.DESCRIPTION
Function used to gather the software application version information in the section above.
Collects the information from the InstallerVersion and ExeVersion properties and reports them into a HTML table.
#>
$AdminTools = [ordered]@{
    "Notepad" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Notepad++"
        "Installed Version" = $Notepad.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Notepad.InstallerVersion
        "Status" = ""
    }
    "PowerShell7" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "PowerShell 7"
        "Installed Version" = $PowerShell7.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $PowerShell7.InstallerVersion
        "Status" = ""
    }
    "PuTTY" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "PuTTY"
        "Installed Version" = $Putty.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Putty.InstallerVersion
        "Status" = ""
    }
    "MTPuTTY" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "MTPuTTY"
        "Installed Version" = $Putty.MTPuttyVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Putty.MTPuttyVersion
        "Status" = ""
    }
    "Rufus" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Rufus"
        "Installed Version" = $Rufus.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Rufus.ExeVersion
    }
    "TFTP Server" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "TFTP Server"
        "Installed Version" = $TFTP.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $TFTP.InstallerVersion
    }
    "VLC Media Player" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "VLC Media Player"
        "Installed Version" = $VLC.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $VLC.InstallerVersion
    }
    "WinMerge" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "WinMerge"
        "Installed Version" = $WinMerge.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $WinMerge.InstallerVersion
    }
    "WinSCP" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "WinSCP"
        "Installed Version" = $WinSCP.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $WinSCP.InstallerVersion
    }
    "WireShark" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "WireShark"
        "Installed Version" = $WireShark.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $WireShark.InstallerVersion
    }
    "NPCap" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "NPCap"
        "Installed Version" = $NPCap.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $NPCap.InstallerVersion
    }
}
$Browsers = [ordered]@{
    "Microsoft Edge" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Microsoft Edge"
        "Installed Version" = $MSEdge.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $MSEdge.InstallerVersion
        "Status" = ""
    }
}
$VMWare = [ordered]@{

    "OVFTool" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "OVFTool"
        "Installed Version" = $OVFTool.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $OVFTool.InstallerVersion
    }
    "PowerCLI" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "PowerCLI PowerShell Module"
        "Installed Version" = $PowerCLI.ModuleVersion
        "Expected Version" = $PowerCLI.InstallerVersion
    }
    "VMware Workstation" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "VMware Workstation"
        "Installed Version" = $Workstation.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Workstation.InstallerVersion
    }
    "VMRC" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "VMware Remote Console"
        "Installed Version" = $VMRC.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $VMRC.InstallerVersion
    }
}
$Satcom = [ordered]@{
    "Airbus M&C" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Airbus Monitor & Control"
        "Installed Version" = $AirbusMC.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $AirbusMC.InstallerVersion
    }
    "Airbus KA-Band SSPB Software" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Mission Microwave UserGUI"
        "Installed Version" = $AirbusKA.InstallerVersion
        "Expected Version" = $AirbusKA.InstallerVersion
    }
    "Airbus Spec Any" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "EVO Spectrum Analyzer"
        "Installed Version" = $AirbusSpecAny.InstallerVersion
        "Expected Version" = $AirbusSpecAny.InstallerVersion
    }
    "Wavestream" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Wavestream UserGUI"
        "Installed Version" = $Wavestream.InstallerVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Wavestream.InstallerVersion
    }

}
$SDCApps = [ordered]@{
    "NetBanner" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "NetBanner"
        "Installed Version" = $NetBanner.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $NetBanner.InstallerVersion
    }
    "Axway" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Axway"
        "Installed Version" = $Axway.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Axway.InstallerVersion
    }
    "ActivClient" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "ActivClient"
        "Installed Version" = $ActivClient.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $ActivClient.InstallerVersion
    }
    "90Meter" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "90Meter"
        "Installed Version" = $90Meter.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $90Meter.InstallerVersion
    }
    "Titus Classification" = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Application = "Titus Classification"
        "Installed Version" = $Titus.ExeVersion
        "Expected Version" = $Titus.InstallerVersion
    }
}


Switch ($Enclave){
    NIPR {
        $SDCApps.Remove("90Meter")
        $SDCApps.Remove("Titus Classification")
        $PreContentHeader = "<h2>TDC Management Laptop Application Baseline Versioning Table - <span style='color:green'>NIPR</span></h2> 
        <h3>Report Run: <span style='color:red'>$(Get-Date)</span> by <span style='color:red'>$([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)</span></h3>"
    }

    SIPR {
        $SDCApps.Remove("ActivClient")
        $PreContentHeader = "<h2>TDC Management Laptop Application Baseline Versioning Table - <span style='color:red'>SIPR</span></h2> <h3><p id='ReportDate'>Report Run: $(Get-Date) by $([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)</h3>"
    }
}

$Header = @'
<style>
    body {
        background-color: Gainsboro;
        font-family:      "Calibri";
    }

    table {
        border-width:     1px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        border-collapse:  collapse;
        width:            75%;
    }

    col {
        width: 20%;
    }

    th {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: #98C6F3;
    }

    td {
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          5px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     black;
        background-color: White;
    }

    td[value="wrong"]{
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    tr {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #00ff00;
    }
   
</style>
'@


$Title = "<h1>TDC Management Laptop Application Baseline Versioning Table - <span style='color:green'>NIPR</span></h1>
<h3>Report Run: <span style='color:red'>$(Get-Date)</span> by <span style='color:red'>$([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)</span></h3>"

$Admin = $Admintools.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -precontent "<h3>Administrator Tools</h3>"
$Browser = $Browsers.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>Web Browsers</h3>"
$VMWareApps = $VMWare.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>VMware Applications</h3>"
$SatcomApps = $Satcom.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>SATCOM Applications</h3>"
$SDC = $SDCApps.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>SDC Applications</h3>"




ConvertTo-Html -Body "$Title $Admin $Browser $VmWareApps $SatcomApps $SDC" -Head $Header | Out-File "C:\Source\BuildSource\Laptop\Application_Verification.html"



Invoke-Item "C:\Source\BuildSource\Laptop\Application_Verification.html"

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the question is. Are you looking to color a specific cell? Are you looking to know if it's possible? Your question should be more specific

Comment: I've edited the post, but my question is how do I change either a cell color or text color based on a conditional value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reproduce your code without having all variables defined beforehand hence I'll use below example object to demonstrate how this can be done.

```bash
$adminTools = @(
    [ordered]@{
        "Application"       = "PowerShell 7"
        "Installed Version" = [version] '5.1'
        "Expected Version"  = [version] '7.2.6'
    }
    [ordered]@{
        "Application"       = "PuTTY"
        "Installed Version" = [version] '0.77'
        "Expected Version"  = [version] '0.77'
    }
)
```

I have added these 2 classes to your current CSS:

```css
.bad {
  background-color: #ffc7ce;
  color: #9c0006;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.good {
  background-color: #c6efce;
  color: #006100;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

First part is adding the status column based on the condition if `Installed Version` is lower than `Expected Version`:

```bash
$export = foreach($item in $adminTools) {
    $item['Status'] = 'Up to Date'
    if($item['Installed Version'] -lt $item['Expected Version']) {
        $item['Status'] = 'Needs Update'
    }
    [pscustomobject] $item
}
```

Now we can use [`Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) combined with a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0) that we can use to replace the `<td>` tag for the the `<td>` tags with the clases depending on the matched value in the capturing group:

```bash
$map = @{
    'Up to Date'   = '<td class="good">'
    'Needs Update' = '<td class="bad">'
}

$html = $export | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $style -Head '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
[regex]::Replace($html, '(?i)<td>(Needs Update|Up to Date)', {
    param($s)
    $map[$s.Groups[1].Value] + $s.Groups[1].Value
}) | Set-Content test.html

Invoke-Item test.html
```

**Demo of how this would look using the example objects**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: Gainsboro;
        font-family: "Calibri";
      }

      table {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 75%;
      }

      col {
        width: 20%;
      }

      th {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        background-color: #98C6F3;
      }

      td {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        background-color: White;
      }

      .bad {
        background-color: #ffc7ce;
        color: #9c0006;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .good {
        background-color: #c6efce;
        color: #006100;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      tr {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #00ff00;
      }
    </style>
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <th>Application</th>
        <th>Installed Version</th>
        <th>Expected Version</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PowerShell 7</td>
        <td>5.1</td>
        <td>7.2.6</td>
        <td class="bad">Needs Update</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PuTTY</td>
        <td>0.77</td>
        <td>0.77</td>
        <td class="good">Up to Date</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! with some tweaking I was able to get this to work and it looks great!
for my own knowledge though, for the regex, what is ```(?i)```? I'm guessing its like a ```where item``` kind of thing.
and also out of curiosity, is it possible to add a third property to the ```$map```? I know I'd need to specify a class in the CSS section and to the map, but is there anything I need to change in the regex? would I need to write it as so: ```[regex]::Replace($html, '(?i)<td>(Needs Update|Up to Date|Old Installer Present)'```

Comment: @Fitzgery `(?i)` is a modifier that makes it case insensitive, by default, `[regex]::Replace(...)` is case sensitive. Yes it's possible to add as many properties to the map as you want but for it to work you need to add that property to the regex too `(....|....|mynewproperty)`

Comment: thanks for the info again! I can never wrap my head around Regex(too many symbols lol) I thought it might be that simple for the map, I've given it a try and it's not working atm, but I'll keep digging away at it