# Using HTML in PowerShell to highlight output

Tags: html, powershell

I have a powershell script with the following that creates an HTML table:

```
    ### Create HTML
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

    # Client Secret Reminder Notification


#If (($ReminderSecretCount -gt 0) -and ($NewSecretCount -eq 0)){   # uncommnet if using NewSecretCount
If ($ReminderSecretCount -gt 0){  # remove if using NewSecretCount
$ReportDate = get-date -format d
$AppReport = "<H3>Client Secret Expiration Notification Report - $ReportDate</H3>"
$AppReport += ""
$AppReport += "<H5>30 Day Client Secret Expiration Notification Summary</H5>"
$AppReport += $ReminderSecret | Select-Object AppName,SecretName,EndDate,SentTo,AutoRenewal | Sort-Object enddate | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
}
```

The output is as follows:
.[image: Output of html]

If AutoRenewal = No, I'd like to highlight that row in red or have the font color be read.   How can I add that to my code?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add that table as CSV so we can use that data to share an example of how this is done? basically you need to put a placeholder before the property value where value is `No` and then replace that placeholder with a CSS class

Comment: Here you have an example of what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739013/powershell-change-cell-color-in-html-table-based-on-value-or-if-statements/73739368#73739368

Comment: If you don't mind downloading a module from the PowerShell Gallery, [ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/EnhancedHTML2/2.1.0.1) adds a bunch of options for things like conditional formatting. The author even wrote a [free eBook](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/creating-html-reports-in-powershell/) for the topic.